# Not able to prevent kubectl pod from recreating

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to delete a pod that was created while editing and testing deployment.

I am extracting the pod configuration with

`kubectl get po jenkins-774896bc77-tc8cg -n infrastructure -o yaml --export=true > a.yaml`

Then I am editing the `a.yaml` file and replacing `restartPolicy` to `Never`.

Then I tried to run `kubectl replace -f ./a.yaml -n infrastructure` and `kubectl apply -f ./a.yaml -n infrastructure`

But in both cases I am getting:

`error: error when replacing "./a.yaml": resource name may not be empty`

Any advice how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this for deployment as deployment manages pods.

```
kubectl get deployment <your_deployment_name> -o yaml > a.yaml
```

and then do the rest part as you did `kubectl replace -f ./a.yaml -n infrastructure`